# Current measurement with LT6015, simulation doesn't work

Tags: current-measurement, current-sensing

I'm trying to simulate high side shunt resistor current measurement using LT6015 op amp, but the simulation doesn't work I'm always having the same output even if I change the current. Can somebody tell me why?

[image: schematic]

*[lt6015 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/601567ff.pdf)*

Comment: Hi, ZACK. Welcome to EE.SE. You will get more attention and better responses if you write with proper capitalisation and punctuation. See [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It looked like the voltage shown on the schematic on the other side of the shunt was 0.00000002 V, but it's actually 8.80000002, which I saw more clearly when I enlarged the image. I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems. As Spehro notes, the 3.3V power supply is connected backwards. You will also clip the output with a 0.2V input. Either change the gain, the current sense resistor, or the 3.3V power supply to 5V.

If you simulate your circuit with a sine wave input, you can see the part saturating.

[image]

Comment: thanks @qrk it work nowww ::

Answer (score 1):

You've reversed the power supply connections on the LT6015. You've burned out the chip. Delete it and download a new one.

Comment: The V+ to V- absolute max rating is 60V, -50V. No virtual smoke.

Comment: It would be fun to write a script or add-on to LTspice to detect destructive conditions and display a GIF of an actual fire or explosion. :)

Comment: thankss i was doubting about that